# Website showing old data even after updating

Tags: caching, cloudflare

I have a problem with my website. The updated content is not displaying correctly. Instead, it shows old data. Sometimes, the updated content appears in the Incognito window, but not always. Also, the content is updated on one computer but not on another. This inconsistency is concerning because it affects the user experience and causes users to leave the website. I have checked that the settings on this website are the same as my other websites where this issue doesn't happen.

I've attached a screenshot of the Cloudflare Page rule for your reference. Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help.

[Screenshot of Cloudflare Page Rule Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOQp3.jpg)

Clearing the cache on Cloudflare is a simple process that is the same for all websites. However, this particular website did not clear the cache automatically, despite me bypassing the cache using a page rule.

I might find experts here in Stack Overflow to help me with my problem.